# BITCOIN payments, OP_RETURN parameter

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment, php-5.3, bitcoin

I want to automate **BITCOIN payments** and i need to make a donate button that sends an aditionally **OP_RETURN** parameter with the value of the encrypted order id. I just want to send a small message with the payment. I have documented myself a little bit and i saw that **OP_RETURN** parameter may help me.

OP_RETURN :
http://bitzuma.com/posts/op-return-and-the-future-of-bitcoin/

How do i make that happen? Is there a wallet that does that? Or I have to do it from `bitcoin-cli`?

I also want to make this in `PHP` and here is an example that i don't understand :
https://github.com/coinspark/php-OP_RETURN

I mean i need a button that will make a payment with that encrypted order id.

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to do that server side via encrypted and authenticated client using BIP 70 - AKA The Bitcoin Payment Protocol.

You can create a browser side client to do as you described but you do not want to trust the data the client sends along without verification and you checking the transaction before it is sent to the network will not make you trustworthy as a merchant but rather a MIM between the user and the blockchain.

For more information on BIP 70 The Payments Protocol
See: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0070.mediawiki

Comment: actually i solved this with `blochckain.info` website, they provide some proxy BTC purses that stand between the payer and your account, and whenever i get a payment on that porxy purse, i confirm the payment instantaneous with some secret passwords, and i also use a AJAX request on my website for 5 to 5 seconds to check if the payment is confirmed, here is a link : `https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive`, what do you think about this? I think is more easier and clean the learning the `Bitcoin Payment Protocol`.

Comment: No argument against how much easier that will be, the payment protocol is new but will be made into the standard way to run your own payment system if you are developing the complete transaction service.

Comment: this time i made this in CodeIgniter (some usefull models), nextime i can do a class that does that, so i can do my own standard way, isn't that great?